# Why does the Cluster Governing Registry specify two types of databases in it's instructions?

Tags: wso2, clustered-index

Please disregard this if already asked, but I'm curious to know why the Clustering Governance Registry 5.x.0 documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Governance+Registry+5.x.0) specifies two types of databases in its initial setup. It first starts out with MySQL and then switches over to specifying an H2 repository. Yet, the driver class for the H2 database appears to be defined for MySQL under the "WSO2_CARBON_DB local datasource configurations" section.

I also don't see where the referenced worker database is initially defined. Is that something that needs initializing or becomes automatically created elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the "master-datasources.xml" file in a freshly unzipped G-Reg pack, this "WSO2_CARBON_DB" datasource entry is already in there. So, you no need to add it again. Instead of that, you just need to add "WSO2_CARBON_DB_mount", "WSO2_USER_DB" and "Social DB" datasources only(as I explained in the other post)